# Shouldn't the chain rule be applied instead of the product rule in linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

If I have the linear operators $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, and i want to calculate the derivative of $A(B(x))$, shouldn't it be:

$$A(B(x))'= A'(B(x))B'(x)$$

Instead of $(AB(x))'= A'(x)B(x) + A(x)B'(x)$ ?

This may not make much sense, but if you think about this linear operators as matrices, when we have $AB\vec{x} $, should't we undestand it as "$A(B(x))$", instead of "$A(x)B(x)$"? After all A is acting on $x$ transformed by "B", not in $x$ itself.

I am making this stupid question because I am trying to study QM through Functional analysis and operator theory, but when I came to this example I thought about something that I hadn't thought before and now I am in doubt, sorry for the silly question.

It came from this check @littleO :

"Let $A(x)$ be an operator (It probably means a linear operator,but you know how physicists are!) dependant on a continuous variable x, define its variable by:

$$\frac{dA(x)}{dx} \equiv  A'(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{A(x+\varepsilon)-A(x)}{\varepsilon}$$

If $A$ has an inverse show that

$$\frac{dA^{-1}}{dx}= - A^{-1}A'A^{-1}$$

Show also that

$$\frac{dAB}{dx}= A'B+ AB'$$ "

Comment: Yes, you apply the chain rule here. You need to distinguish between $A (x)$, which is a vector that depends on $x$, and $A$, which is a linear operator and does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Yes @Zhen Lin, but my point is that a matrix is a linear operator, and it is well know that the derivative of the product of matrices is given by the product rule, instead of the chain rule.

Comment: I'd be curious to see a screenshot from your book that shows where this issue arose.

Comment: It is in portuguese, and is one of some small check exercises in the middle of the text.

Comment: But I will add a translation here anyway @littleO.

Comment: In the equation for $A'(x)$, what type of object is $\epsilon$ and what type of object is $x$?

Comment: Well , It could be anything really, can you see my problem with it? Although now I am confident in what it meant.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are taking the derivative with respect to!

Suppose you have two different operators $A_t$ and $B_t$, which *depend on time*.  At each moment, each operator is a function from your Hilbert space to itself, and so has a derivative with respect to the quantum state.  In that case, you do apply the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(A_tB_tx)=\frac{\partial A_t}{\partial x}(B_tx)\frac{\partial B_t}{\partial x}(x)$$

On the other hand, since $\{A_t\}_t$ and $\{B_t\}_t$ are each a function from time to the set of operators on your Hilbert space, it too has a derivative with respect to time.  Since $x$ is constant in time and composition coincides with multiplication for linear operators, we can apply the product rule: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(A_tB_tx)=\left(\frac{\partial A_t}{\partial t}B_t+A_t\frac{\partial B_t}{\partial t}\right)x$$

(I've ignored issues with whether these derivatives exist and are bounded, in what sense they exist (Gateau/Frechet), how to handle if x might vary in time too, etc.  But you mentioned you came to this from physics, so you probably don't need to know/can guess how to handle those.)

Comment: Physicists pay their functions better and functions work harder for them (apologies to Lewis Carroll).  In particular, every series is uniformly convergent, so you can interchange limits and differentials/integrals.

Comment: Is this an actual quote by Lewis Carroll? I mean it probably isn't and is some quote on Alice in Wonderland, but it could as well be, being that he was a Mathematician know as Charles Lutwidge Dodgson.